# activity snooping over SSL by client administrator

Tags: tls

I am trying to understand the **extent** to which SSL certificates secure the content (or activities) over SSL. Here is my understanding:

Under a **hypothetical** condition:

1. Person-A is the Administrator of a windows laptop.
2. Person-B is a non-admin user of that laptop.

**My understanding:**

When person-B visits a CA-Signed SSL certified site (https://example.com), the activities (Eg: writing a comment, etc) done within the site are hidden (encrypted) from everyone including Person-A (admin), however, Person-A may see the **domains** Person-B visited.

If the above is true, is it also applicable when Person-B visits a site with a self-signed certificate if person-B trusts the self-sign certificate?

Comment: Is person A also using the laptop at the same time?

Comment: Assuming, not using the same time.

Comment: so ... how would the admin see the content of person b's activity even if TLS wasn't used at all?

Comment: your counter-question makes sense. I was mainly concerned about SSL/TLS encrypted content visibility to privileged users via some snooping tools like tcpdump, browser extensions, post-analysis via logs etc. what if used at the same time?

Comment: Also, I am sorry as I am still figuring out things. so my question itself IS not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A privileged user is able to install some software doing network interception  and also add a new trusted root CA. This together makes it possible to do an active MITM attack on the TLS traffic, and thus listen and even modify the traffic. This is similar to what many antivirus products do.

Comment: Another solution is for the admin to hook into the targeted programs (eg. using a debugger) in order to extract the TLS connections secrets (master secrets, etc.) and use these to decrypt the traffic without an active MITM.